# Github Actions: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0

Tags: android, continuous-integration, github-actions

i am using Github Actions to automate releases of my app to Play Store. The deployment step uses [r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/upload-android-release-to-play-store).

The step is configured as follows:

```
  - name: Deploy to internal test track
    uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
    with:
      serviceAccountJsonPlainText: ${{ secrets.PLAYSTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
      packageName: com.android.myapp
      releaseFiles: app/build/outputs/bundle/release/*.aab
      track: internal
```

The action fails with the error: `Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0` which I assume is from the attempt to parse the `service-account.json` file saved in `base64` format in secrets.

The original file contains valid `json` and ideally shouldn't contain any errors. What could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save decode base64 and save in file location then give serviceAccountJsonPlainText file location like example code.

```
serviceAccountJsonPlainText: file_path/google_service_account.json
```

Comment: or use another action 
https://github.com/r0adkll/upload-google-play

Comment: Please use [edit] to add more information instead of putting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my implementation worked when I saved the `service-account.json` file in plain text instead of `base64` encoded format.